# Minimum time to assign Holes to Mices

Tags: algorithm

There are n Mices and n holes placed in a straight line.Each hole can accomodate only 1 mouse. A mouse can stay at his position, move one step right from x to x+1, or move one step left from x to x−1. Any of these moves consumes 1 minute.

We need to find minimum time so that all mice are assigned holes.

Example : Let N=3 and Mices are at positions = [4,-4,2] and holes are at position [4,0,5]

Then here answer is 4.

Explanation :

```
Assign mouse at position x=4 to hole at position x=4 : Time taken is 0 minutes 
Assign mouse at postion x=-4 to hole at position x=0 : Time taken is 4 minutes 
Assign mouse at postion x=2 to hole at postion x=5 : Time taken is 3 minutes
```

After 4 minutes all of the mice are in the holes. So the answer is 4.

I think sorting both arrays and then find corresponding difference of element will serve the purpose.But am not able to get a proof that weather it will be minimum.

So please help.

Comment: Can there be more than one mouse at a hole initially, or during the move?

Comment: @Thomas We can assume no two holes can be present at the same position.Also their can never be more than one mouse at any time.

Comment: What about mice though?

Comment: @Thomas I replied.At one hole their will always be one mouse

Comment: How many cats are there ?

Comment: @PaulR No cat..Bad luck..;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `i1 < i2` be the positions of two mice and let `j1 < j2` be the positions of two holes. It suffices to show via case analysis that

```
max(|i1 - j1|, |i2 - j2|) <= max(|i1 - j2|, |i2 - j1|),
```

since it follows by induction that every assignment can be transformed by a series of swaps into the sorted assignment, where none of these swaps increases the makespan.

Comment: You mean my prposed algorithm of sorting is correct?